# Essentially a 2 dimensional Enum?

Tags: c#, software-design

Not sure how to phrase this, but I have a class called Lane for different lanes of a road.

A Lane has two parts - the Direction (an Enum of left or right or other) and then the number, an integer. So lanes look like this: L1, L2, R1, R3 etc..

There should only be one instance of the lane class for each lane. L1 shouldn't exist twice.

Because of this, I want to be able to assign the Lane of an object the way you can assign an enum, by typing Lane.L1 or Lane.R4 etc.. I currently have to use a method which finds the existing Lane object that corresponds to the Lane I'm trying to reference.

Is this a way to do this better? Like by simply typing lane = Lane.L1, other than making the Lane class have private constructors and manually creating a public Getter for each possible Lane and assigning references in a static constructor for the Lane class?

This is the current state of the lane class:

```
public enum Direction { INCREASING = 1, DECREASING = 2, BOTH = 3, OTHER = 4, UNSPECIFIED = 5 }
public class Lane : IComparable
{
    public Direction Direction;
    public int Number = 1;
    public Lane(Direction direction, int number = 1)
    {
        Direction = direction;
        Number = number;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Direction == Direction.UNSPECIFIED)
        {
            return Direction.AsCharLR().ToString();
        }
        return Direction.AsCharLR() + Number.ToString();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Lane)
        {
            Lane l = obj as Lane;
            return Direction == l.Direction && Number == l.Number;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)Direction * 100 + Number;
    }

    public static Lane Parse(char lane)
    {
        lane = char.ToUpper(lane);
        switch (lane)
        {
            case 'L':
            case 'I':
                return new Lane(Direction.INCREASING);
            case 'R':
            case 'D':
                return new Lane(Direction.DECREASING);
            case 'B':
                return new Lane(Direction.BOTH);
            case 'U':
                return new Lane(Direction.UNSPECIFIED);
            case 'O':
            default:
                return new Lane(Direction.OTHER);
        }
    }
    public static Lane Parse(string text)
    {
        Lane lane = Parse(text[0]);
        lane.Number = int.Parse(text.Substring(1));
        return lane;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object l)
    {
        return GetHashCode() - l.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to make it single instance? Is it because, you need to perform equality check on them (which can be overcome by overriding `Equals`)? Or, other reason?

Comment: You could just implement it as an 1D enum, unless the lane number is dynamic. You could also implement some sort of caching to avoid duplicated instance and expose it via `static Lane Get(Direction, int)`. There is many ways of solving this, but without context, it is hard to say which is the best or the right one.

Comment: Show  a concrete example (in code) of what you want, this is very unclear

Comment: "There should only be one instance"... what is the scope of this statement? If it's "the entire application", then you want singletons, in which case - yes, you'd have public static getters on Lane for each one.

Comment: How many lanes are there going to be? You could just make it a standard enum and be done with it..

Comment: Each L1 is the same as every other L1. Like an enum it doesn't need any other information than what is it its name: L and 1. So I thought making a class was overkill. I also thought there might be a better way to do it then using a static Get method because that requires logic and processing. Maybe there was a way to point straight to the existing lane object like an enum.instance. Sorry for being confusing I am trying to be as clear as I can

Comment: May be up to 6 lanes for each direction - but sometimes direction and number are referenced independently and I so I would like to keep them separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want with an `enum` because it doesn't sound like you're placing a limit on the "number" part, and you can't define or use new enums at runtime.

This might be all you need:

```
public static class Lanes
{ 
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Lane> LanesDictionary = 
        new Dictionary<string, Lane>();

    public static Lane GetLane(Direction direction, int number)
    {
        var key = direction.ToString() + number;
        if (LanesDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return LanesDictionary[key];
        }
        var lane = new Lane(direction, number);
        LanesDictionary.Add(key, lane);
        return lane;
    }
}
```

Now every time you reference `Lanes.GetLane(Direction.INCREASING, 4)` you'll always get the same `Lane`. If it doesn't already exist it will be created.

That gets you a convenient, readable way to reference a given lane. If for some reason you wanted shorthand for some lanes - although, as mentioned, you don't want to hardcode them (I wouldn't either) - you could do this:

```
public static Lane L4 { get; } = GetLane(Direction.INCREASING, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you said you didn't want private constructors, but what if you had public static attributes, like the following?:

```
public class Lane
{
    private Direction direction;
    private int number;

    public static Lane L1 = new Lane(Direction.INCREASING, 1);
    public static Lane L2 = new Lane(Direction.INCREASING, 2);
    //add more ...

    private Lane() { }

    private Lane(Direction d, int n)
    {
        this.direction = d;
        this.number = n;
    }

    public enum Direction
    {
        INCREASING = 1, DECREASING = 2, BOTH = 3, OTHER = 4, UNSPECIFIED = 5
    }
}
```

This way you can type `lane = Lane.L1`, and it always return the same instance.
Is this enough?

Comment: This looks pretty good! I was wondering if there was a way to do exactly this, but without hard coding all of the possible lane values?
In this case it's very possible; but it may not be for different, future applications

Comment: Yes, by using `dynamic` variables and `ExpandoObject`.